# How to pass an array in place of a pointer to a function

Tags: html, c++, arrays, pointers

I have following function myfunc which takes std::span as a variable.

```
const foo*  foos     = nullptr;
uint32_t    fooNum = 0;

std::span<const foo> fooSpan = std::span<const foo>(foos, fooNum);

myfunc(fooSpan)
```

Now I have another set of variables in array form

```
const foo fooArray[];
uint32_t  numfoo = 0;
```

Is this the correct ways to call myfunc() with these variables

```
std::span<const foo> fooSpan = std::span<const foo>(foosArray, numfoo);
myfunc(fooArray)
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve], or at least more code. It's a bit unclear what you're asking

Comment: not clear what's `myfunc` declared as or what `foosArray` is, so question is not clear.   A correct and complete code example required

Answer (score 1):

If `myfunc` got prototype of

```
void myfunc (std::span<const foo>);
```

Then `myfunc(fooArray)` would be legal only if `fooArray` is array of `const foo` and have initializer available, or is an `std::array`, i.e. its size can be deduced to consider which constructor of `span` will be used, e.g.

```
using foo = int;
const foo arrFunc[] = {3,4,5};
std::array<const foo,3> arrFunc2{3,4,5};

void myFunc(std::span<const foo>) {}

int main()
{
    myFunc(arrFunc);
    myFunc(arrFunc2);
}
```

Using something like `myFunc({arrFunc,numfoo});` also possible, that'd be creating a `span` in place, in that case `arrFunc` can be a pointer.